# Remove Base url from $http.get - angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I am new to angular 2 and I am trying to make an http request to the spotify Api to get data using the following code.

**Service**:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class SpotifyService{
    private searchUrl: string;

    constructor(private _http:Http){
       // this.searchUrl = ''; 
    }

    searchMusic(str:string, type="artist"){
        this.searchUrl = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=${str}&offset=0&limit=20&type=${type}&market=US`;
        console.log(this.searchUrl);
        return this._http.get(this.searchUrl).map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

**Component**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router'; 
import {SpotifyService} from '../../services/spotify.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'search',
    templateUrl: 'search.component.html',
    providers: [SpotifyService]
})

export class SearchComponent {

    searchStr:string;

    constructor(private _spotifyService:SpotifyService){

    }

    searchMusic(){
        //console.log(this.searchStr);
        this._spotifyService.searchMusic(this.searchStr).subscribe(res => { console.log(res.artist.items)});
    }
}
```

While making the request to the API, I am getting this error

> EXCEPTION: Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL:
>   http://localhost:3000/https/api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=a&offset=0&limit=20&type=artist&market=US

In the console, the value of `this.searchUrl` is

> https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=a&offset=0&limit=20&type=artist&market=US

but while making the request its adding the base url i.e `http://localhost:3000` in front of it. How can I remove this base url from the `searchUrl` so I can make the request to the spotifyAPI.

Comment: can  you provide me proxy.config.json file@kiiiinnnnnnnnnyyyy

Answer (score 0):

Using a reverse proxy will allow your Spotify API query to work properly.

Some background: Direct access to servers other then the one serving your web page are not allowed by default by most browsers for security reasons. This includes both your host name and port used by your web server.
[developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

This can be overcome by using a reverse proxy. Configuration will depend upon your web server used to serve the page as it will be required to make the API invocation on behalf of your web page and then relay the results back.

If you are serving your Angular 2 App with "ng serve", you can configure your proxy as follows:

Create a new JSON file in your base project directory named "proxy.conf.json"

Add the following content:
    
     `{
       "/v1": {
           "target": "https://api.spotify.com",
           "secure": true,
           "changeOrigin": true,
           "logLevel": "debug"
       }
     }`

Open package.json and locate the start command. It will look something like this: "start": "ng serve"

Make the following change: `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"`

Now modify your SpotifyService http invocation as follows:

```
this.searchUrl = `/v1/search?query=${str}&offset=0&limit=20&type=${type}&market=US`;
```

Comment: i have never faced this issue with any any specific reason for this approach